# FB App cant post Image to page?

Tags: php, facebook, image

I recently created a Facebook App to send visualized data (image) to pages which are already belongs to same user account as The App.

Also, I set extended permissions in Permissions Pane of App. Setting Page.

Here are the codes that can send post in text format. But when I tried to send images attached it fails.

What are the possible mistakes that I can't get at the moment?

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'               => MY_APP_ID,
    'secret'              => MY_APP_SECRET,
    'fileUpload'          => true,
    'allowSignedRequest'  => false
));

$img        = "../../../tw-data/postImages/twpostimage-usd.png";    
$message    = 'Activity Test with Image @ ' . date('d.M.Y H:i:s');

try
{
    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    $params = array('access_token'  => $access_token,   
                    'source'        => '@'.$img,
                    'message'       => $message
                );

    $result = $facebook->api('/'. MY_PAGE_ID .'/feed','POST', $params);  
    print_r($result);  
}
catch (FacebookApiException $e)
{
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
    echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
    error_log($e->getType());
    error_log($e->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What Errors are you getting when you try this?

I believe the main issue you're having is that you're posting to

```
/my_page_id/feed
```

where you should be posting to

```
/my_page_id/photos
```

From the [facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/)

```
$response = $facebook->api(
     "/me/photos",
     "POST",
     array (
        'url' => '{image-url}',
    )
);
```

EDIT:

I have successfully posted an image with a message using the following format.

```
$img        =  'FILE_NAME.jpg';    
$message    = 'Activity Test with Image @ ' . date('d.M.Y H:i:s');


$params = array('access_token'  => $access_token, 
                'message' => 'test',
                'source' => '@'.$img
            );

$result = $facebook->api('/USER_ID/photos','POST', $params);  
print_r($result);
```

Comment: I tried several times '/my_app_id/photos' but each time it raised the following error : Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#324) Requires upload file ... er

Comment: I changed array parameter to "url" and assigned image URL It posted text but not image :(

Comment: Strange, 

You're sure the image is at the link provided as well? You might try testing it with a picture that's uploaded somewhere already.

Comment: still nothing changed

Comment: Check my updated answer, I am able to properly post an image with a message using that request.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, I set extended permissions in Permissions Pane of App. Setting
>   Page.

That's a common mistake. Permissions have to be requested in your scope, not in the app settings.

```
$params = array(
 'scope' => 'publish_stream',
 'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.myapp.com/post_login_page'
);
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

Accept the permissions dialog and try again. If you want to post to the page as page, obtain a page access token.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Also see my answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541335/cannot-get-page-like-for-some-users/20561696#20561696